# How is it that $P(RL^C)$ is equal to $P(R)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a formula which says:

$$P(R | L^C) = \cfrac{P(RL^C)}{P(L^C)} = \cfrac{P(R)}{1-P(L)}$$
I understand how $P(L^C) = 1-P(L)$, but can't find the formula which would allow $P(RL^C)$ to equal $P(R)$

The context behind the problem is: Joe is 80 percent certain that his missing key is in one of the two pockets of his hanging jacket, being 40 percent certain it is in the left-handed pocket and 40 percent certain it is the right-hand pocket. If a search of the left-hand pocket does not find the key, what is the conditional probability that it is in the other pocket?

R -> the event that it is in the right hand pocket
L -> the event that it is in the left hand pocket

Comment: Can you give some more context here?  What are $R$ and $L$?  How are they related to each other?

Comment: This holds iff $$P(R\cap L)=0$$

Comment: @NickPeterson I made an edit to the question to reflect the context.

Answer (score 1):

$R$ and $L$ are disjoint events, so $R \subset L^C$. Hence, $RL^C=R$.

Comment: In words: Event $R$ is that the coin is in the right pocket. Event $RL^\complement$ is that the coin will be in the right pocket and not in the left pocket. Since it is impossible for the coin to be in both pockets, $R$ and $RL^\complement$ are the exact same event. So of course they have the same probability measure. $${\because R=RL^\complement\\\therefore ~\mathsf P(R) =\mathsf P(RL^\complement)}$$